# Weird behaviour when overlaying PNGs

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I want to put [this image](https://images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/pieces/neo/150/bb.png) on top of [this image](https://images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/boards/green/150.png).

This is my code:

```
public class ImageOverlayTest {
    public static final String IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH = "src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images/chess-sources/";
    public static final String IMAGE_DEST_PATH = "src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/images/games/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedImage bgImage = readImage("board", "png");
        BufferedImage fgImage = readImage("bb", "png");
        BufferedImage overlayedImage = overlayImages(bgImage, fgImage);
        writeImage(overlayedImage, "result", "png");
    }

    public static BufferedImage overlayImages(BufferedImage background,
                                              BufferedImage foreground) {
        Graphics2D g = background.createGraphics();

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);

        g.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return background;
    }

    public static BufferedImage readImage(String fileNameWithoutExtension, String extension) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            String path = IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH + fileNameWithoutExtension + "." + extension;
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }

    public static void writeImage(BufferedImage img, String fileNameWithoutExtension,
                                  String extension) {
        try {
            String path = IMAGE_DEST_PATH + fileNameWithoutExtension + "." + extension;
            File outputFile = new File(path);
            ImageIO.write(img, extension, outputFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Mainly taken from [here](http://blog.icodejava.com/tag/java-draw-one-image-over-another/).

The result looks like this:
[image: image with wrong overlay]

What is going wrong? Why is it not renderig the top image the same way as when you look at it individually? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: try add g.setRenderingHints(KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY). See also [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html)

Comment: that does not change the result :(

Answer (score 0):

Something about the color profile of the background image must have been wrong. I converted it to jpg and back to png using GIMP, now it's working fine ;)